# as3 draw with mouse and erase lines when hitTestObject is reached

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, hittest

I am trying to create a simple hitTestObject and see the lines that are being drawing on screen hit with a Ball. If it does it will erase all lines and start fresh. I am very close.  The checkIt() function is where the code needs to happen and its clearing the lines but not making a new shape.

**How can I erase the lines the mouse drew and start fresh when a hit test is reached?**

```
var myshape:Shape;


myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xC807DE);
var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
alreadyDrawn = new Shape();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, activateDraw);
function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    function lineDraw(myevent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
        function stopDraw(endevent:MouseEvent):void
        {
            alreadyDrawn = myshape;
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);

        }


        myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
        myevent.updateAfterEvent();
        checkIt();
    }


}

function checkIt()
{
    if (alreadyDrawn.hitTestObject(Ball) == true)
    {
        trace("Hit The Balls");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xC807DE);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have ONE shape instead of two, because once you do `alreadyDrawn=myshape` you lose whatever object you attached there. You should instead do `alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);` this will copy all the strokes from argument to object without losing the other instance.

Next, you seemingly need to also stop drawing if you've detected a hit vs `alreadyDrawn`, for this, call `stopDraw(null);` from `checkIt()`.

And next, you are not clearing all the listeners off stage while adding more and more. See, if you draw several lines in quick succession (press-drag-release), the `stopDraw` listener is added multiple times and not removed even once. To do this, use `removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);` inside `stopDraw` function and move the adding line into `activateDraw`, because there are multiple "mouse move" events while you drag the mouse, and another listener is added each time you process the event.

And finally, PLEASE don't nest functions without actual need!

The fixed code should be this:

```
var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xC807DE);
var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
alreadyDrawn = new Shape();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, activateDraw);
function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
    checkIt();
}
function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function checkIt()
{
    if (alreadyDrawn.hitTestObject(Ball) == true)
    {
        trace("Hit The Balls");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xC807DE);
        alreadyDrawn.graphics.clear(); // clear this too
        stopDraw(null); // stop active draw, if any
    }
}
```

[`copyFrom()` manual reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom%28%29)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the great code. I did get this error: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 25 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method copyFrom through a reference with static type flash.display:Shape.

Comment: Oops, `copyFrom()` is a `Graphics` class method, and accepts another `Graphics` object as source. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for all the code again. I am still having issues. In short what I want to do is create a drawing game for kids. They "press" button to start(makes new shape) then draw, if they hit an object it starts over and erases lines and all objects drawn. Or they can do the same thing by hitting "start" again. But my code is very buggy, even with the changes you made. I know its close tho. Its a maze game. so when they hit wall they go back to beginning.

Comment: You should provide more details of those issues. Maybe you should move to `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection` library (search for it) because `hitTestObject` has a lot of issues as is.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question~

I think the problem may be you forgot to `moveTo` after `clear`.

Here is my fix:

Pass `mouseX`, `mouseY` to `checkIt`.

```
checkIt( mouseX, mouseY );

function checkIt( mouseX:Number, mouseY:Number ):void
{
    if (alreadyDrawn.hitTestObject(Ball))//you don't need == true here
    {
        trace("Hit The Balls");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xC807DE);
        myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    }
}
```